# Fastlane scan returns error No test bundle product for testingSpecifier

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-scan

I’m trying to run my project's Unit Test cases on my current project but when I run the command:

```
fastlane scan
```

It returns this error message:

> xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace TruDoc24x7 with scheme TruDoc24x7CI.
>   Reason : No test bundle product for testingSpecifier.

I also tried to write a lane for testing and add parameters to specify my workspace and scheme:

```
lane :tests do
    run_tests(
        workspace: "TruDoc24x7.xcworkspace",
        scheme: "TruDoc24x7CI")
end
```

Can anyone tell me the reason for that error?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I ran into similar errors